# Lotus Notes to Oracle database migration

Tags: oracle, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, database-migration

I have a NSF file of a lotus  database. The objective is to give up the legacy lotus notes database and migrate it to relational database oracle. Do any one have expertise in this area to give a step wise process to carry out migration from lotus notes to oracle db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 years ago I integrated Domino and Oracle and well it was pretty impressive.

I googled migrate from domino to oracle and didn't find much more than the LEI (or DECS) to allow connection of DATA between the 2 systems.
some steps:

1 analyze the NSF: size (MB or GB ?) number of form/view  logic in code (my 5 cents opinion find someone that really use the DB that explain what they use in it !)

2 form/view will be table and requests in Oracle

3 data migration : all text date ... will be strate forward. BUT attachment Rich Text and in lined image will be painfull

4 logic well you will have to rewrite all no formula/lotuscript/xpages to J2EE or else

read also http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/answer/Migrating-from-Domino-to-Java-and-Oracle