# How to migrate existing database from Domino Server to Relational database (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, xml, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there any good way to migrate existing database from Domino Server to Relational database like MySQL without using any tool.

I've explored a bit about this and got to know that its possible using XML but don't know how and what'll be the procedure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: kinda duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473488/lotus-notes-to-oracle-database-migration

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer: That is about migrating domino to java or oracle. I want domino to mysql, php.

Comment: yes but SQL server and Oracale are both relationnal, thus no big difference.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any tool: NO.

There are two big difficulties in exporting data:

First is the Notes Richtext, which is a proprietary format that has to be "transcoded" somehow. This is not an easy thing to do "manually" and needs either a lot of coding or some kind of tool.

Second is the fact, that there is no "forced" structure in Notes documents. There can be several forms that "define" how the documents look and there can be different versions of these forms that have been used over the past. A document may or may not contain any number of fields in any thinkable type (the field may even be number in one document and text in the other).

You have to KNOW the structure of your documents to get them out. Of course you can simply export them as "Structured Text" or as "Comma separated values", to get -most- of it, but then you need views that show the documents in the order you need them. Exporting them as XML is another "standard" way to get the data, but then you need to understand the xml to get it into your relational database.

Short: Without (at least very little) coding knowledge OR a tool (that costs money) there is no chance for getting the data out.

Ah yes, there is an "ODBC driver" for Lotus Notes / Domino, but that will not help you much, if you do not know the structure of your documents and how Notes- Databases work, it will also not work.

Comment: What you think about this : http://waset.org/publications/4574/data-migration-between-document-oriented-and-relational-databases

Comment: Nice theory... but not one hint about "how to do this"... You can try the mentioned tools, but the article itself does not provide any solution itself. It is a "cookbook" to write the software to do this...

Answer (score 1):

As Torsten said above, you can't do it without a tool, either you buy one or write one yourself.

I wrote a tool like that several years ago to export Notes databases as XML. There is a bit of work, especially with the rich text fields. You also may want to export/detach attachments and embedded images.

You can read more about my export tool here: http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter